# How to keep the selected checkmark box selected in a TCheckListbox control after using the .Move() method

Tags: delphi

I am trying to re-sort the checkboxes that are presented to the user by a button click to go up or down. I can get the checkmark boxes to resort successfully on each click but the problem is that the selected checkmark box loses focus after I click on the button. This makes it so that I cannot keep clicking the button to continuously move the checkmark box up or down. I have to re-select the checkmark box to continue moving it.

Can somebody help me with keeping the focus on the checkmark box after each button click?

**My Code**

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, CheckLst;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CheckListBox1: TCheckListBox;
    upButton: TButton;
    downButton: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure upButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure downButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation
 {$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.downButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:Integer;
 begin
  i:=CheckListBox1.ItemIndex;
  if(i<CheckListBox1.Count-1) Then
    CheckListBox1.Items.Move(i,i+1);//Here
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('One');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Two');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Three');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Four');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Five');
  CheckListBox1.Items.Add('Six');
end;

procedure TForm1.upButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:Integer;
begin
  i:=CheckListBox1.ItemIndex;
  if(i>0) Then
    CheckListBox1.Items.Move(i,i-1);//Here
end;

end.
```

Comment: The item loses the focus (`ItemIndex` is set to -1) most probably because the item is deleted (and inserted somewhere else) in the `TListBoxStrings` collection. At least you can setup the `ItemIndex` to the new index manually after you move the item (e.g. `CheckListBox1.ItemIndex := i + 1;` when moving down). I don't know (nor believe) that you can prevent this behavior somehow.

Comment: That worked though. That is the answer thanks. Even though it actually did lose focus it makes it look like the focus was not lost by manually setting the index. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a method for calculating the new index and another for moving and follow the item. Then you will have a more speaking, DRY and reuseable for any control derived from `TCustomListBox` code:

```
procedure TForm1.MoveAndFollow( ListBox : TCustomListBox; OldIndex, NewIndex : integer );
begin
  ListBox.Items.Move( OldIndex, NewIndex );
  ListBox.ItemIndex := NewIndex;
end;

procedure TForm1.MoveCurrentItem( ListBox : TCustomListBox; MoveUp : Boolean );
var
  LOld, LNew : integer;
begin
  LOld := ListBox.ItemIndex;
  if MoveUp then
    LNew := LOld - 1
  else
    LNew := LOld + 1;
  if 
    Math.InRange( LOld, 0, ListBox.Count -1 )
  and 
    Math.InRange( LNew, 0, ListBox.Count -1 )
  then
    MoveAndFollow( ListBox, LOld, LNew );

end;

procedure TForm1.downButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  MoveCurrentItem( CheckListBox1, False );
end;

procedure TForm1.upButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
begin
  MoveCurrentItem( CheckListBox1, True );
end;
```

Comment: @TLama My answer is more to give the idea of DRY and reusable code for such kind of tasks. For sure it can be improved in any way, as long as it keeps DRY :o)